# What is the function of this controller and what does different settings do?

Tags: electrical, switch, heating, floorheating

I moved into a new house last week and I cant seem to understand what the function of this controller in my fuse box is, it says heating controller on the box but there is no details.
Also note that the heating is under floor and each room has its own thermostat to control heating.

Can you please explain what are the different settings on it and how to set it up?

Heating controller 750 E1 E6

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Doing random searches, I searched for 750 E1 E6 and found this datasheet.

http://www.winterspm.com/wp-content/uploads/Operating-Instructions-for-Cuirt-Seoige-Underfloor-Heating.pdf

Comment: It looks like that it controls the heating in your flooring and attempts to anticipate outside weather changes since slab heating lags temperature changes. Your floors will always be warm but these systems often overshoot and undershoot on days with large  outdoor temperature swings.